# IntelliJ startup error - Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-15

when I am trying to start my intelliJ it gives the below error in my Windows 7:

Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressManager.getInstance must not return null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:201)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:360)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressManager.getInstance must not return null
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.getInstance(ProgressManager.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:505)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:194)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: The earlier question was asked for android studio, which is not exactly same as Windows IntelliJ, I guess!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After third restart, it worked automatically, I don't know the reason.

Comment: Yes. it is really a very strange behaviour. But it is true. In my case it worked after the second start with the  error message.

Comment: Sometimes this problem cause because you have unsupported JDK version. This method didn't work for me. Intellij IDEA supports java 8. So i remove all the java version on my laptop and then intall java 8 using $sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: it did not work for me. refer [https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004973960-Critical-Internal-Error-on-Startup-of-IntelliJ-IDEA-Cannot-Lock-System-Folders-](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004973960-Critical-Internal-Error-on-Startup-of-IntelliJ-IDEA-Cannot-Lock-System-Folders-). This helped me. I executed ```netsh winsock reset``` suggested by Serge Baranov and it worked.

Comment: Made fourth attempt, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Sameer Khan as for me the only helped way was a installation of new version with "uninstall  previous and install new one by keeping old settings" option checked. Then added lost plugins .

Comment: For me, I deleted one of the plugins which was incompatible with the version of PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, i just restarted my computer again and then it got fixed, oops :)